# Using IO::Socket::IP with Mojo::IOLoop

Tags: perl, sockets, mojolicious

I am trying to achieve what these lines of code do synchronously, but asynchronously via Mojo::IOLoop and Mojo::Promises:

```
my $address = '192.168.1.240';

my $sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(PeerAddr => $address,
                          PeerPort => '9999',
                          Proto    => 'tcp');

$sock->send($on);

my $data;

$sock->recv($data, 2048);

print $data;
```

This is used to communicate with a smartplug, and a promise-based interface would allow me to abstract out things, so that different plugs (some communicating via HTTP, some via TCP) could be handled in the same way.

Right now I've achieved the result by doing this

```
sub talk_to_plug_p {
    my ($addr, $command) = @_;

    my $promise =  Mojo::Promise->new;
    my $port = 9999;

    my $sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(PeerAddr => $addr,
                                   PeerPort => $port,
                                   Proto    => 'tcp');

    return $promise->reject("Could not open socket on $addr at port $port") unless $sock;

    my $id = Mojo::IOLoop->client({ handle => $sock } => sub {
                                      my ($loop, $err, $stream) = @_;

                                      $stream->on(read => sub {
                                                      my ($stream, $bytes) = @_;

                                                      # -------------------
                                                      # THIS LOOKS BAD
                                                      # -------------------
                                                      remove_id($loop);
                                                      $promise->resolve($bytes);
                                                  });

                                      $stream->on(error => sub {
                                                      my $err = shift;
                                                      $promise->reject($err);
                                                  });
                                      $stream->write($command);
                                  });

    sub remove_id { shift->remove($id) };

    return $promise;
}

talk_to_plug_p('192.168.1.240', $on)->then(sub { print @_ })->catch(sub { print shift });

Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;
```

Now this *works* but it kind of looks wrong - especially the `remove_id` part, and I imagine there must eb a better way than this. I just could not find it.

What would be a cleaner way? i.e.: one that closes the client when bytes have been read, or where I can explicitly close the connection or something similar.

Comment: Re "*but asynchronously via Mojo::IOLoop*", Yet you're still using IO::Socket::IP. Do you have a reason for creating the connection synchronously instead of using `Mojo::IOLoop->client`?

Comment: @ikegami - no, not strictly. The docs say you can pass a handle to `Mojo::IOLoop->client` ("takes the same arguments as "connect" in Mojo::IOLoop::Client") - and I took the chance. I had tried to use `Mojo::IOLoop::Client` directly and it did not work.

Comment: It's just `my $id = Mojo::IOLoop->client( address => $address, port => 9999, sub {...} );`

Comment: @ikegami - done, it works but still looks barbaric

Comment: That didn't address your question. I've never used Mojo::IOLoop before, so I just commented one thing I saw

Comment: What do you think `$sock->recv($data, 2048);` does? Do you think that reads 2048 bytes? It doesn't, and neither does your new code. (It reads whatever bytes are available up to 2048. If none a present, it waits for some bytes to arrive first.) The new version similarly reads a random amount of bytes.

Comment: If the point is to end before reaching the end of the stream, maybe `$stream->close` would make more sense than removing the client?

Comment: @ikegami - yes, though I'm not familiar with perl networking (I'm waiting for a book to come in the mail) I understand that it just reads up to 2048 or waits. The switch interface has been designed like this - it would have been far better with http but that's not something I control. It's described here https://www.softscheck.com/en/reverse-engineering-tp-link-hs110/ So, closing the stream seems to do the job too. I'll read the book to understand why. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think of streams like a phone call. You can talk as long as you want. Eventually, someone has to hangup for whatever reason. They might let the other know first (like "goodbye"), or they could do it abruptly. But either way, someone's going to hang up. The equivalent is closing the socket, which is done by closing the stream here. The loop, knowing the connection is closed, resolves promises that depended on that.

Comment: @ikegami - thanks for the explanation. I'll dig through Network Programming with Perl by Lincoln D. Stein when it arrives to understand more. Apologies for the way the question was asked - I'm not a professional, and sometimes it's hard to even know what the thing you want to do is called, and the docs take it that you'd know the basic concepts already. Would you want to turn this into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't want really want to spend time installing the module, writing an answer, testing it. Feel free to do so, though :)